# Apache wicket Tomcat Problem: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, filter, wicket

I am new to Apache Wicket and I am trying to make a simple program in Eclipse, in order to practice. I have trouble making it work; maybe there is a problem in the configuration with Tomcat or some option in Eclipse.

HelloWorld.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1 wicket:id="message">Hi, World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloWorld.java

```
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;

public class HelloWorld extends WebPage {
    public HelloWorld() {
        add(new Label("message", "Hello, World!"));
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>simple-wicket</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
        <filter-name>helloworld</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>general.HelloWorld</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>helloworld</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have downloaded the corresponding wicket jars (where the org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter is included as a .class), I have synchronized this web project with Tomcat 7 and when I am trying to run I receive the following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter helloworld
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1955)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1798)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:5037)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone know how I could fix that? I have JDK 1.8, in case it matters.

Thanks in advance!

edit: This is the structure of the project:
[Structure in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPbPF.png)

Comment: How are you building this?  It sounds like the Wicket jar is not being included in your web application.

Comment: In this example I did not use any building tools, but in one of my previous attempts I used Maven, which helped me dowload the wicket jars. In this project I added the jars via Build Path option in project's properties (it's in the referenced libraries). Should I move them to a different location? The wicket-core jar is the one having the filter class. I have edited the original post in order to include the structure of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that in the Apache Wicket version I had (7.5.0) the apache wicket libraries were not loaded to Tomcat and I had to manually add them in Project>Properties>Web Deployment Assembly. After that it worked fine.
In other Apache Wicket versions I had tried (e.g. 7.16.0) the webpage had worked fine without that kind of procedure. I haven't understood why Eclipse faced these 2 cases differently, but I share this information in case anyone else faces a similar problem.
Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Thanks! I added the Java Build Path entries to the Deployment Assembly and the startup of tomcat worked

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use the Maven based QuickStart project: http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html

This way Maven will make sure all needed dependencies are at the class path. In Eclipse just open Start.java class in the test folder and Run/Debug it as normal Java class with main() method.
You may also use Eclipse Maven integration if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I followed these steps and I had the same exception.

Comment: Please share your mini project somewhere, e.g. at GitHub, so we can take a look. Please add the steps you execute in the README